# Dealing with spotty (mobile) connection and API

Tags: php, mysql, api, http, mobile

I'm currently building an API which is being accessed over HTTP by a mobile app. Assume the following scenario: Mobile app sends an HTTP POST request to www.example.com/customers containing registration data, the API connects to the database, inserts a new record and returns 200 OK plus some user specific registration data.

Now suppose that the insert in the database went fine, but the 200 OK response never made it to the mobile app, bad connection/user switched off mobile connection etc. Obviously repeating the same POST request isn't going to work because a user with that username/id is already present. How would I solve this (and protect other functionality in the API using the same mechanism)?

Also, while I was thinking about the above scenario, might the same problem arise between the webserver and the database server as well? E.g.: PHP scripts calls mysql_connect() to connect to the (remote) database and a call to mysql_query() is made. Could it happen that the database server committed the query but for some reason the PHP script never received the "OK" from the db connection due to a bad connection or anything like that?

Comment: First off, ignore the fact that it's mobile - just think about how you make the transaction(s) atomic - meaning that the remote device controls the completion status - it's a long subject, too long for a comment - but done every day.

Comment: @KevinDTimm thanks for your input. The transactions aren't my problem. Perhaps I wasn't very clear. At one point the transaction completed successfully and the remote side is about the be notified, what to do when this fails? (On a TCP level) Since it isn't critical for the transaction to complete, the database contents are most likely altered but nobody was notified.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a transaction id per request to verify that the actual request has been completed.

Let me elaborate; For each request made by the mobile app you assign a transaction id on the request made. The server performs the action, saves the transaction as completed and returns with a message like: {"result": 200, "transaction": 1234123}.

If the client does not receive the success message (due to a network issue), it will re-transmit the request with the same transaction id. When the server receives the message, it will know that the transaction has already been completed and respond accordingly to the client.

You should probably use UUID for the transaction ids to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Yeah that would probably work, some kind of nonce really I guess. My API also exposes functions that increase/decrease a counter. That could be used to prevent repeated duplicate HTTP requests to accidentally inc./dec. those counters.

Answer (score 0):

Store session variables that you can use to identify if a process has been completed, or use something like an ajax call to repeatedly attempt to load a results page that will only render once the transaction has been properly recorded.

As far as the communication between the script and the database goes, the code will continue to execute regardless of the browsers connection status, so your code will always get the response from MySQL and finish executing as expected.

Comment: In the last paragraph of my question I wasn't talking about the browser<-->webserver connection. Imagine mysql_query just sent the "COMMIT" to the db server (or a single auto committed statement). The mysql server is now going to respond to the script about the COMMIT cmd that was executed, what if the connection fails at that point?

Comment: At that point an exception is thrown by PHP, and you have a major infrastructure problem on your hands.

Comment: Any idea how to deal with this? Could it ever be that mysql_query() returns failure but that the actual query has been committed in this case?

Comment: If your connection to the database is under so much uncertainty, I think your best bet would be to have a local MySQL instance that you could guarantee a connection to and replicate using a methodology that minds greater than mine have already worked out long ago.